# I have a segmentation fault in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a segmentation fault in the following code, but do not understand why. This is part of a larger program, where fsi is a double and is calculated immediately preceeding this block of code. The program calculates fsi over a number of years (lt) and I want to print the output as an array (fsi.dat). It prints the first value but then seg faults. What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
FILE *fpout;
int lt; 
double silicate[lt];
fpout = fopen("fsi.dat","w");
 if(fpout == NULL) 
    ferrx("writedat(): Can't open file to write: fsi.dat");
 for(i=1;i<=lt;i++)
    silicate[i] = fsi;  
    fprintf(fpout,"%18.15f \n", silicate[i]);
 fclose(fpout);
```

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=lt;i++)` --> `for(i=0;i<lt;i++)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to put brackets in order to execute more than one statement in a `for`

```
for(i=1;i<=lt;i++) {
    silicate[i] = fsi;  
    fprintf(fpout,"%18.15f \n", silicate[i]);
}
```

The version you have is equivalent to

```
for(i=1;i<=lt;i++) {
    silicate[i] = fsi;  
}
fprintf(fpout,"%18.15f \n", silicate[i]);
```

the last line executing with `i = lt + 1`

Comment: And also the "c arrays are 0 based" issue that Guntram found.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=1;i<=lt;i++)
    silicate[i] = fsi;
```

is wrong, indexes in C are zero-based. So your valid indexes are `0 .. (lt-1)`